# Url accessible with slysh and without slash?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website where a part of the urls are accessible with slash and without slash. Most urls are only accessible with slash. But all the urls with `/espose/Id` in the url are accesible with both. Is there a possibility to make a rewrite rule or something like that for the urls with `/expose/ID` that these are also only accessible with slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
### FORCE TRAILING SLASH ON /ID PAGES ###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [QSA,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
### /FORCE TRAILING SLASH ON /ID PAGES ###
```

You need to put this at the top of your `.htaccess` file.